# Input only number C programming

Tags: c

currently i am doing a program to get the input (0 to 50) from the user.
If the number is out of the range then the number will not be counted.
After that, i will calculate and get the average, maximum and minimum for those
inputs. I facing a problem when the user input character. The program will crack. I wonder how can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=1 , j=1,skor;             //variable untuk jumlah ujian
float total = 0, average;       //variable untuk skor ujian, jumlah dan purata
int min=99999;                  //variable untuk min
int max=0;                  //variable untuk max

printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
printf("*                    Enter test scores,-1 to exit                              \n");
printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
printf("*                                                                              \n");
//masukkan data skor dan perhitungan jumlah keseluruhan skor
while (skor != -1)
{
    printf("* Scores[%d] (0-50) : ", i);
    scanf("%d", &skor);
    if(skor>-1&&skor<51)
    {
        total += skor;
        j++;
    }
    if(skor>max&&skor<51&&skor!=-1)
    {
        max=skor;
    }
    if(skor<min&&skor>=0&&skor!=-1)
    {
        min=skor;
    }
    i++;
}
j=j-1;
//pengiraan purata
average = total / j;
//printf("\nJumlah = %.2f\n", Jumlah);
//printf("\nj = %d\n", j);
printf("*                                                                              \n");
printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
printf("* \n* Average marks = %.2f                                 \n", average);
printf("*                                                                              \n");
printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
//pemaparan nilai min dan max
printf("*                                                                              \n");
printf("* MIN:%d \n", min);
printf("* MAX:%d \n", max);
printf("*                                                                              \n");
printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I want to limit that the input is only for integer value and not allow the user to input a character so that the program will not crack.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of correctly read inputs. Use that result to verify that valid input was given.

Comment: @frozen i do not want the user to input the character.. limiting the input to number only.. how can i do this?

Comment: `namespace` can not be used in C.

Comment: @Evert how to verify the valid input?

Comment: Use an if-statement...

Comment: check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @Evert i already use if-statement to verify the number in range. But i do not know how to verify if the input is a character.

Comment: Read my first comment more carefully. Read the manual page for scanf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. There are a number of questions on SO about how to write C code that ensures that the user enters a (only) a number. Collectively, they outline the alternative options available to you. You're probably best off using line-based input ([`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and parsing with
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Comment: @Evert sorry I not that good in programming.. i still cant understand how to do it..

Comment: `if (scanf("%d", &skor) == 1) { /* read int */ } else { /* show warning about attempting to read a non-int */ }`

Comment: scanf returns the number of correctly read inputs: if scanf asks for an int, and you give it one, it'll return one. If you give something else, scanf fails to read it correctly, hence it'll return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose among options:
A. Take input as string and then verify if the string is number. Else, discard it.
B. Trap key downs. If if is alphabet or symbol, discard. If 0-9, use it.

Comment: Do you know of any portable way to "Trap key downs" ? And how do you intend to handle back strokes, back strokes after non numeric characters? Please post a complete answer. This qualifies just to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int get_int(const char *prompt){
    char buff[32];

    for(;;){
        fputs(prompt, stdout);fflush(stdout);
        if(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin)){
            if(strchr(buff, '\n')){
                char *endp;
                long n;

                errno = 0;
                n = strtol(buff, &endp, 10);
                if(errno == 0 && *endp == '\n' && INT_MIN <= n && n <= INT_MAX)
                    return n;
            } else {//too long input
                while(getchar() != '\n');
            }
        } else {//input EOF
            continue;//ignore EOF
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int n = 0, score, min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
    double total = 0, average;

    printf("Enter test scores,-1 to exit\n");
    while((score = get_int("* Scores[%d] (0-50) : ")) != -1){
        if(score < 0 || score > 50)
            continue;

        total += score;
        if(score > max)
            max = score;
        if(score < min)
            min = score;
        ++n;
    }
    if(n){
        average = total / n;
        printf("Average marks = %.2f\n", average);
        printf("MIN:%d\n", min);
        printf("MAX:%d\n", max);
    } else {
        puts("No valid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why that complicated? Why not `if (scanf("%d", &skor) == 1)`?

Comment: @Evert `50abc` , `111111111111` must be an invalid input.