# fgets() doesn't work as expected in C

Tags: c

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int testcase;
 char arr[30];
 int f,F,m;
 scanf("%d",&testcase);
 while(testcase--)
 {
  printf("Enter the string\n"); 
  fgets(arr,20,stdin);
  printf("Enter a character\n");
  F=getchar();
  while((f=getchar())!=EOF && f!='\n')
    ;
  putchar(F);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&m);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I want a user to enter a string, a character and a number until the testcase becomes zero.

My doubts / questions:

1.User is unable to enter a string. It seems `fgets` is not working. Why?

2.If i use `scanf` instead of `fgets`,then `getchar` is not working properly, i.e whatever character I input in it just `putchar` as a new line. Why?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&testcase);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &testcase);` Skip the newline  after the number.

Comment: `fgets` reads up from FILE until a new line is encountered. But your very first use of `scanf` is leaving the '\n' character in the input stream, which is then consumed by `fgets` and it thinks the input is done.

Comment: why do we need to skip the new line after the number?

Comment: That newline is received in `fgets`.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905009/reading-newline-from-previous-input-when-reading-from-keyboard-with-scanf

Comment: Is it the same with getchar,because when i use scanf instead of fgets,it putchar only a new line?

Comment: whatever keystrokes you'll hit on your keyboard will be stored in `stdin`.  Therefore, you'll have to consume that extra new line character `'\n'`, because it is there in the input stream.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No good if they type a number then press space then press enter

Comment: Use like [get_int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45180914/971127) instead of.

Comment: Better not to mix `scanf()` with `fgets()` to avoid these troubles; try using `fgets()` with `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()` alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing functions like `fgets()`, `scanf()`, and `getchar()` is error-prone. The `scanf()` function usually leaves a `\n` character behind in the input stream, while `fgets()` usually does not, meaning that the next call to an I/O function may or may not need to cope with what the previous call has left in the input stream.

A better solution is to use one style of I/O function for all user input. `fgets()` used in conjunction with `sscanf()` works well for this. Return values from functions should be checked, and `fgets()` returns a null pointer in the event of an error; `sscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments made, which can be used to validate that input is as expected.

Here is a modified version of the posted code. `fgets()` stores input in a generously allocated buffer; note that this function stores input up to and including the `\n` character if there is enough room. If the input string is not expected to contain spaces, `sscanf()` can be used to extract the string, leaving no need to worry about the newline character; similarly, using `sscanf()` to extract character or numeric input relieves code of the burden of further handling of the `\n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int testcase;
    char arr[30];
    char F;
    int m;
    char buffer[1000];

    do {
        puts("Enter number of test cases:");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
            /* handle error */
        }
    } while (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &testcase) != 1 || testcase < 0);

    while(testcase--)
    {
        puts("Enter the string");
        /* if string should not contain spaces... */
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
            /* handle error */
        }
        sscanf(buffer, "%29s", arr);
        printf("You entered: %s\n", arr);
        putchar('\n');

        puts("Enter a character");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
            /* handle error */
        }
        sscanf(buffer, "%c", &F);
        printf("You entered: %c\n", F);
        putchar('\n');

        do {
            puts("Enter a number");
            if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
                /* handle error */
            }
        } while (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &m) != 1);

        printf("You entered: %d\n", m);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if the input string *may* contain spaces, `fgets()` can read input directly into `arr`, but then the stored string will contain a `\n` character, which should probably be removed. One way of doing this is to use the `strcspn()` function to find the index of the `\n`:

```
#include <string.h>  // for strcspn()
/* ... */
        puts("Enter the string");
        /* or, if string may contain spaces */
        if (fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin) == NULL) {
            /* handle error */
        }
        /* replace newline */
        arr[strcspn(arr, "\r\n")] = '\0';

        printf("You entered: %s\n", arr);
        putchar('\n');
/* ... */
```

Note that a maximum width should always be specified when using `%s` with the `scanf()` functions to avoid buffer overflow. Here, it is `%29s` when reading into `arr`, since `arr` can hold 30 `char`s, and space must be reserved for the null terminator (`\0`). Return values from `sscanf()` are checked to see if user input is invalid, in which case the input is asked for again. If the number of test cases is less than 0, input must be entered again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack is to write a function to interpret the newline character. Call `clear()` after each scanf's

```
void clear (void){
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Refer to this question for further explaination: [C: Multiple scanf's, when I enter in a value for one scanf it skips the second scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9562218/7445147)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution how can we use scanf and fgets together safely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int testcase,f,F,m;
 char arr[30];
 scanf("%d",&testcase);
 while((f=getchar())!=EOF && f!='\n')
  ;
 while(testcase--)
 {
  printf("Enter the string\n");
  fgets(arr,30,stdin);  
  printf("Enter a character\n");
  F=getchar();
  while((f=getchar())!=EOF && f!='\n')
    ;
  putchar(F);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&m);
  while((f=getchar())!=EOF && f!='\n')
  ;
 }
}
```

We need to make sure that before fgets read anything,flushout the buffer with simple while loop.

Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: This loop style is a good way to clear the input stream. Good that you are checking for both `\n` _and_ `EOF` (this is really mandatory); also good that you are using `int` instead of `char` for `f`, since `EOF` may not fit in a `char`. Also note that this code has no input validation; for example, the user can enter `a` instead of a number for the last input. This would mean no assignment made to `m`, leaving its value indeterminate (possible undefined behavior ahead).

Comment: You can check the return value from `scanf()` to see if an assignment was made.

Comment: "how can we use scanf and fgets together safely." + not checking the return value of `scanf()` is not "safe".