# check input program gets stuck in an infinte loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that asks to type something and check if it is an integer. If it is an integer, then print "the integer is ...". Else, print "try again" and waits for another input. However, the program prints an infinite number of "try again" if you type in a character. Here's the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
  int inp;
  bool t = 1;
  printf("type an integer\n");
  while (t) {
    if (scanf("%i", &inp) == 1) { 
      printf("The integer is %i", inp);
      t = 0;
    } else {
      printf("try again");
      scanf("%i", &inp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no code to read the non-numeric input.  Add some. Else the  non-numeric input remains in `stdin`.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you use to some kind of reasonable whitespace convention. What you had was gross. I've edited it.

Comment: Did it occur to you that the `scanf` will return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned?

Comment: You might try something like `scan("%*s%i");` to read the integer after `try again`. What you have skips whitespace before the integer, but you need to get rid of the non-whitespace characters.  The `%*s` skips any string of non-whitespace but doesn't assign it to a variable. The `%i` automatically skips leading whitespace.  This still isn't perfect.

Comment: @paul Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @gene fixed. thanks for reminding me

Comment: Actually now that I think if it, you'd do better with `scan("%*[^-0-9]%i", &inp)`, but you can still break this with some inputs.  The bottom line is that `scanf` isn't a great tool for this use case.

Comment: Did you tried removing the scanf from Else statement?
As when you don't enter a number, it will go to while and then check in if again and scan again as well. I think you don't want this behaviour

Comment: @anugrah doesn't seem to work

Comment: @pxc3110 Sorry, I just misunderstood.>_<

Comment: @pxc3110 That wasn't the solution, but I believe the 2nd scanf shouldn't be there as well.

Comment: @gene did you mean "scanf" instead of "scan"? I tried and the infinite loop went away but it didn't work exactly the way I intended it to. When I typed an integer it would say "try again", and when I typed a character such as "w", it didn't print "try again".

Comment: One approach is to check each and every character of the number or string and then do a check like if (ch-'0'==(int)(ch)). This will make sure the input is a number!

Comment: Also, look at this link https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/386198/only-accept-integer-input-with-scanf

Comment: @anugrah Your link is very helpful and I'll take time studying it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45180914/971127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's code fail to consume the offending non-numeric input.  It remains in `stdin`, for the next input function.  As it is unfortunately just another `scanf("%i", &inp)` which fails the same way - infinite loop.

After attempting to read an `int`, read the rest of the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  int inp;
  int scan_count;
  printf("Type an integer\n");
  do {
    scan_count = scanf("%i", &inp); // 1, 0, or EOF

     // consume rest of line
    int ch;
    while ((ch == fgetchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      ;
    }

  } while (scan_count == 0); 
  if (scan_count == 1) {  
    printf("The integer is %i\n", inp);
  } else {
    puts("End of file or error");
  }
}
```

An even better approach would read the line of user input with `fgets()`.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146306/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

When you entered a `char`, the variable `inp` in `scanf("%d", &inp)` would get `null`, since the input that doesn't match the format string. And the character you input would remain in the buffer, so that's the reason both your `scanf` would not stop.

A simplest way to fix this is modify your second `scanf("%i", &inp);` to `scanf("%c", &c);` (don't forget to declare a `char c` in your main function).

Answer (score 0):

check here `while(t)` its in an infinite loop because you have to set a condition for `t` something like while(t==1) or while(t>1) or (t<1) something like that. saying while(t) means that t can be anything and it will continue to run.

Comment: oh I didn't notice t was a boolean

Answer (score 0):

> There is nothing in to break the while loop.

consider getting rid of the boolean, and simply using a while (1) loop with a break. Also you should be using "%d" to indicate an integer in scanf/printf. And there is no need for the scanf call in the else, since your program would loop back and call scanf again anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int inp = 0;
  printf("type an integer\n");
  while (1) {
    if (scanf("%d", &inp) == 1) { 
      printf("The integer is %d", inp);
      break;
    }
    else {
      printf("try again");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: thanks. I executed your code but the same problem persisted. Does it work on your computer?

Comment: Did you type in a 1? in your if block you compare inp to 1, so I would assume you want to detect whether a use types in a 1 in the console.

Comment: scanf will return a 1 if the input is an integer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Nevermind my first comment, scanf returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned.